# Read multiple layers of KML file using R

Tags: r, kml, ogr, import, rgdal

I have a KML that 3970 layers. I am trying to read it into R using the following script:

```
library(rgdal)
lyr <- ogrListLayers("file.KML")
mykml <- readOGR("file.KML","Layer1")
```

This works but what if I want to read all layers; something like:

```
mykml <- readOGR("file.KML",lyr)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes all of them are of the same type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple function can do that for you. Here's how:

```
allKmlLayers <- function(kmlfile){
  lyr <- ogrListLayers(kmlfile)
  mykml <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(lyr)) {
    mykml[i] <- readOGR(kmlfile,lyr[i])
  }
  names(mykml) <- lyr
  return(mykml)
}
```

use it with:

```
kmlfile <- "se\\file.KML"
mykml <- allKmlLayers(kmlfile)
```

Answer (score 5):

Farid Cheraghi's solution works well. Alternatively, you can use `lapply` from the `apply` family of functions (so named because it returns a list) instead of a `for` loop. If you don't care about saving the process as a new function, you can slim the task to three lines:

```
lyr <- ogrListLayers("file.KML")
mykml <- lapply(lyr, function(i) readOGR("file.KML", i))
names(mykml) <- lyr
```